# Restart App on button Click

Tags: ios4

I am working on a quiz app.Where in the last iteration i need to restart application or i need to go to the starting stage of my application.How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using navigationController based approach, you can do `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`

Comment: i am using a ViewBased application.And loading a tableView with startGame option.Now i want to load the base UI from a button click in the tableView

Comment: Please post some code to show how are you managing showing and hiding the views